# Facebook JS API /me/permissions

Tags: javascript, facebook, permissions

In JavaScript we are making request:

```
FB.api("/me/permissions", function(data){ console.log(data); });
```

On average in 1% we get answer:

> {"error":{"message":"unknown error","type":"http"}}

or

> {"error":{"code":2500,"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException"}}

Is that normal?

Comment: it´s not, but without more code it´s hard to say anything. how does your login code look like, and when do you use the api call?

Comment: It is not related to login or another things. Application works normally, this code works normally, but suddenly I see this error. I do rerequest and all works normally again...

Comment: if an api call does not work all the time and you get that access token message, it can indeed be related to login or other things. actually, that error about the active access token indicates exactly that: a problem with the login handling.

Comment: Just as an FYI, I have the a partial of the above problem too. <1% of my API calls result in "{"error":{"message":"unknown error","type":"http"}}
".

There has to be a solution to this, and moreover, sdk.js should handle http errors a little better than this.